# not enough java heap space' r programming

Tags: java, r

I am out of my R depth. I defined a function nGrams (using RWeka) that worked fine when I tried it out, and sometimes it still does.  I do not know how to figure out what environment it works in, what environment I am in when I want to use it, etc.  Any quick tips or can you point me to a webpage that could help? If I have to put in a change environment command every time I use it, that is just fine.  I really do not understand the issue.

here is what I see in my console.

> blog2gramfreq <- nGrams(cleanblogs100000, 2)
>        Error in ls(envir = envir, all.names = private) : 
>         invalid 'envir' argument
>         Called from: top level 
>        Called from: top level 
>        Browse[1]>

```
structure(function (this, private = FALSE, ...) 
{
envir <- attr(this, ".env")
ls(envir = envir, all.names = private)
}, export = FALSE, S3class = "Object", modifiers = "public")
```

I do see nGrams in my Global Environment window.

Answer (score 0):

This was something that came up in a Coursera class blog that i did not find an answer to, at least for R.  Here is an answer that worked for me when I received the "'OutOfMemoryError : not enough java heap space" error in R programming.

options(java.parameters="-Xmx4000m")